# Не удалось установить: ‎30.‎04.‎2019 – 0x8024ce2b (Драйвер для Intel cire i5)

Tags: display, intel, видеодрайвера

Вынудили вы меня еще один написать. Слишком умная система у вас.

Столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу установить драйвер для Intel corei5 (R) UHD Graphics 620 для дисплея. Сама программа обновлений виндовс не хочет устанавливать его, это единственное в списке с именем "Не удалось установить". И проблема не в моем жестком диске, и после переустановки винды тоже ничего не изменилось, так что популистские советы мне не нужны. С сайта Acer пытался установить, не помогло.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93062/discussion-on-question-by-loyale----30-04-2019--0x8024ce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ссылка на дайвера [Win10x64](https://www.acer.com/ac/ru/RU/content/support-product/7227?b=1), другая ОСь видимо не совместима или драйвера уже будут установлены, VGA драйвер есть встроенный Intel (ваш случай) nNVIDIA, если есть NVIDIA то (я вот точно не помню) лучше сперва поставить Intel, а потом nvidia. Также если у вас процессор 7-го поколения (и выше), к примеру Core i5 7200U, там отдельный драйвер VGA Driver (Kabylake).